# Fixing the safety case of the smartphone

Tags: phone

Just yesterday my smartphone's safety cover got broken as in the image below. It's minor damage and my favourite too so I do not want to replace it, at least not now. I want to fix it by using "feviquick". Any other method or hack one would give would be helpful.

I think the case is not bent, but if you see the left part of the case, then it is tored!

I am concerned that any chemical which if I use to fix the cover should not be affecting the back surface of the phone! It's material is plastic, silicone.

[image: Smartphone safety case.]

Comment: Why is the case so bent, did you boil it? What is it made of? Is it silicone, rubber, plastic, metal....?

Comment: I think the case is not bent, but if you see the left part of the case, then it is tored!, it is made of plastic. Also why a downvote ? if it is not suitable in this site then i should delete my question.

Comment: Not my downvote but if you want any of us to think about a quick fix for your  cover you may not get a good answer without telling us about the material.

Comment: Its plastic,silicon type material!

Answer (score 1):

Use some silicone sealant to glue it back together. Prep by wiping with alcohol and hold side in place with tape for 24 hours while the sealant sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not willing to use any chemical, then I would suggest you use the following method depicted in the image.

Use scissors to cut precisely the extra bulging area, use [fevi quick](https://5.imimg.com/data5/HO/LL/MY-39824384/fevi-quick-small-500x500.jpg) to glue the two parts together(you may need to apply some force) and wait for the glue to perform the action.

[image]